# Get by custom field in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

In PouchDB `.get()` realize searching in documents by `id`. Is that possible to get documents not by id, but by custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You should read about `views` in PouchDB/CouchDB to learn more. Here's a good post to get started: https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html